# How to cascade delete in Grails?

Tags: grails, cascade

I have a domain A which have hasMany domains B and C. B has belongTo A and C have hasOne A relationships.

I am deleting A but it throws error of "Referential integrity constraint violation:".

Now I want that when I delete A its related B and C records delete too.

Comment: Have you set `belongTo` on domains B and C? Then the cascading should happen automatically: http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html

Comment: In B belongTo is set and in C hasOne set.

Comment: First you need to delete relationship domains, then you can delete your master domain

Comment: Include `all-delete-orphan` as in @alexanderfranke's link

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks but doesn't this also remove C the moment you remove it from A? That is different to just deleting C when A is deleted, isn't it?

Comment: I think you have your domain relationships wrong. I think you should setup like this. domainA hasMany domainB, domainA hasOne domainC. Both domainB and domainC belongsTo domainA. Now when you delete domainA, it will do cascade delete. And read this page too. http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html

Comment: @alexanderfranke oh. i had to read your response 4x to get it. :D Yes, it will delete on removing C from A as well. But OP didn't say it would be bad. If it is not acceptable then things should be deleted separately. B and C first and then A.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
@Transactional
void deleteA(Long id) {
     A a = A.get(id)
     def listOfB = B.findAllByA(A)
     listOfB*.delete()
     def listOfC = C.findAllByA(A)
     listOfC*.delete()
     A.delete(flush: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Grails documentation has a section specifically for this:

http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html